# data list is not sortable properly

Tags: javascript

I want to sort this record and my input array is a1

```
var a1 = ["ap1","ap10","ap11","ap2","ap3","ap4","ap5","ap6","ap7","ap8","ap9"];
```

out put should be like :

```
["ap1","ap2","ap3","ap4","ap5","ap6","ap7","ap8","ap9","ap10","ap11"];
```

Here is the code,

```
    var a1 = ["ap1","ap10","ap11","ap2","ap3","ap4","ap5","ap6","ap7","ap8","ap9"];

    var a2 = a1.sort(function(a,b){
    var charPart = [a.substring(0,1), b.substring(0,1)],
    numPart = [a.substring(1)*1, b.substring(1)*1];

    if(charPart[0] < charPart[1]) return -1;
        else if(charPart[0] > charPart[1]) return 1;
        else{ //(charPart[0] == charPart[1]){
            if(numPart[0] < numPart[1]) return -1;
            else if(numPart[0] > numPart[1]) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    });

    alert(a2.toString());
```

Comment: for this input array its sorting perfectely...var a1 =["A1", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B10", "B2", "F1", "F12", "F3"];

Comment: but i am passing input as var a1 = ["ap1","ap10","ap11","ap2","ap3","ap4","ap5","ap6","ap7","ap8","ap9"];

Answer (score 2):

```
var charPart = [a.substring(0,1), b.substring(0,1)],
numPart = [a.substring(1)*1, b.substring(1)*1];
```

You seem to have forgotten that the *char part* of `apN` strings is **2** characters long :-) For a more generic solution, you might use something like

```
var charPart = [a.match(/^\D*/)[0], b.match(/^\D*/)[0]],
    numPart = [+a.replace(/^\D*/, ''), +b.replace(/^\D*/, '')];
```

Comment: ok for my input what should be the code like   var charPart = [a.substring(0,2), b.substring(0,2)],
numPart = [a.substring(2)*2, b.substring(2)*2];

Comment: The `*1` is only to convert the string to a number and doesn't need to be changed, but yes.

Comment: @ Bergi :Thank you so much

Comment: `match` is much slower than `substring`. Be careful!

Comment: @ant_Ti: That's true, but if we don't know the number of letters before we'll have to resort to regexes. Of course, one might optimse this by deconstructing the values only once insted of for every comparison…

Answer (score 1):

```
var a1 = ["ap1","ap10","ap11","ap2","ap3","ap4","ap5","ap6","ap7","ap8","ap9","ap9", "ap9"];

var a2 = a1.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.replace("ap", ""), 10) - parseInt(b.replace("ap", ""), 10);
});

alert(a2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dQD9F/

Comment: var a1 = ["a3p1","a5p10","a8p11","ap2","ap3","ap4","ap5","ap6","ap7","ap8","ap9","ap9", "ap9"]; input data is not sorting properly...if i put somethng

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
var a2 = a1.sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a == b) {
      return 0;
   }

   var charParts = [a.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''), b.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')],
       numParts = [parseInt(a.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10), parseInt(b.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10)];

   if (charParts[0] != charParts[1]) {
       return charParts[0] > charParts[1] ? 1 : -1;
   }

   return numParts[0] > numParts[1] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bergis Answer, theres also no need for a `if` `else` construct in the Number part.
You can instead simply return the difference

```
    var a2 = a1.sort(function (a, b) {
        var charPart = [a.match(/^\D*/)[0], b.match(/^\D*/)[0]],
            numPart = [+a.replace(/^\D*/, ''), +b.replace(/^\D*/, '')];
        if (charPart[0] < charPart[1]) return -1;
        if (charPart[0] > charPart[1]) return 1;
        return numPart[0] - numPart[1]
    });
```

### Update:

```
var a1 = ["a3p1", "a4p2", "ap8a1", "a8p10", "a4p10", "ap8a4", "a8p11", "a9p2", "ap3", "ap4", "ap5", "ap6", "ap7", "ap8", "ap9"];
var a2 = a1.sort(function (a, b) {
    var _a = a.split(/(\d+)/);
    var _b = b.split(/(\d+)/);
    var len = Math.min(_a.length, _b.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        var c = +_a[i],
            d = +_b[i];
        if (c===c) _a[i] = c;
        if (d===d) _b[i] = d;
        if (_a[i] !== _b[i]) {
            return _a[i] > _b[i] ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return (_a.length - _b.length);
});
console.log(a2); //["a3p1", "a4p2", "a4p10", "a8p10", "a8p11", "a9p2", "ap3", "ap4", "ap5", "ap6", "ap7", "ap8", "ap8a1", "ap8a4", "ap9"]
```

Here is an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ejeqin/1/edit):
*This sorts the Array,taking account for all number parts*

Comment: If the question was about code golf, I'd use `return (charPart[0]>charPart[1]) - (charPart[0]<charPart[1]) || numPart[0] - numPart[1]` :-)

Comment: @Bergi I just wanted to point out that the result of the difference is already what the if condition is, checking and returning.
Nothing about code golfing =)

Comment: var a1 = ["a3p1","a4p10","a8p11","a9p2","ap3","ap4","ap5","ap6","ap7","ap8","ap9"]; this input data is not sorting properly could you please give me the solution

Comment: @Manu updated and corrected the answer, but you didn't made completely clear how the sort should work, so i did it the above way